# Replacing the values of a particular number of columns with zeroes

Tags: pandas, dataframe, replace

I have a dataframe with 9 columns. I need to replace all values of columns 3-9 with zeroes and leave the values in other columns as they are. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can simply use iloc which has following syntax:

dataframe_name.iloc[rows, columns]

As you want to replace all values of columns 3-9 with zeroes and leave the values in other columns as they are:

```
dataframe_name.iloc[: , 3:10] = 0
```

Here we have used slicing. for rows I have used ':' which means all the rows and for the columns I have used '3:10' which means all the columns from index 3 to 9 both inclusive